# Is it possible to have expand abbreviations when calling a skeleton-read?

Tags: abbrev, skeleton

I have a large set of abbreviations I defined inside an abbrev-table. Take one of them:

```
(define-abbrev-table 'latex-mode-abbrev-table 
  '(("ff" "my abbreviation!" 0 nil)))
```

If I run a predefined function that calls things through `skeleton-read` is there a way to expand abbreviations within that query? In other words if I define a function,

```
   (define-skeleton myfunc  ""  "" (setq v1 (skeleton-read "put something ")))
```

and call it with `M-x` then within the bottom bar where I type in the value can I use my abbreviation (by typing `ff` and then hitting the space bar) while typing there (nothing happens by default)?

Answer (score 2):

`skeleton-read` will read from the minibuffer, which is a separate buffer that's not using `latex-mode`, which is why your abbrev isn't working there.

You could put your abbrev in `global-abbrev-table` so it's also available in the minibuffers, you could do:

```
(define-skeleton myfunc
 ""  ""
 (setq v1 (minibuffer-with-setup-hook
              (lambda () (setq local-abbrev-table latex-mode-abbrev-table))
            (skeleton-read "put something "))))
```

to make latex-mode abbrevs available in this specific minibuffer.